# Additional JWT for storing sensitive data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm working on a concert ticket E-Commerce website.
There is a Microservice that is called from the UI returning all the Ticket price a user can buy on the web site.

Once the user place the order I don't want to query again the service to get  the price, but I want use the one that was showed on the UI and passed in the HTTP POST request. But I want also make sure that the Payload (price) hasn't been amended.

I was thinking to add this info as Custom JWT (Json Web Token) with a claim that contains the price.

I don't want to add this info to the oAUTH token as it not all services will need to access this information.

Is it a best practice having 2 JWT (one carrying the identity and one any sensitive info I want to protect)

Comment: I would go with something more easier.  Pick a key, concatenate the values which must be concise with the key, hash them all together, and send the checksum with the form, when the user Posts the data you can check if they have the same result for the hash.

Comment: I was thinking to use JWT because that's what they do. If I want to use JWT which way is better (add claim to Auth token or add a new JWT just for this?)

Comment: jwt token is used for authorization, it shouldn't be used to store information like ticket price... I know you can add a claim like `prc` to store the price, but I don't think that's a good practice.

Comment: @TinyWang that's not true. Following the definition of JWT: 

JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA or ECDSA

It's broadly use for auth but it's juts a signed container of data